# Change row stacking on responsive site depending on viewport - Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a test page that has a container (not fluid) within which there are 2 div class="row clearfix" within which there are 3 div class="col-sm-4 column" with each containing text.
When the page is at full width I see 2 rows each containing 3 blocks of text, as the screen gets narrower the text gets narrower until eventually all the text blocks stack up on each other to create 6 rows of text blocks.

What I would like to happen is, when the screen gets narrower there is a point where it goes from 2 rows each containing 3 text blocks to 3 rows each containing 2 text blocks, and then eventually to 6 rows as before.

Is there a class within TBS 3 that allows this, or does the fact that it is "col-sm-4 column" mean that it's always going to be 2x3 then 6x1?

I've had a good look around and tried a few things, but I can't get what I'm after.

(bootstrap.css in the head, and  src="js/jquery.min.js" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" src="js/scripts.js" just before the closing body tag.)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
            <p>
                Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a fiddle or some code, otherwise I doubt anyone will help

Comment: Thanks Fabio, have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Just include your code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
            <p>Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it will work just as you want. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmx9b72r/)

Comment: Just tried it, it still goes from 2x3 to 6x1, without the 3x2

Comment: Thanks in spades for your help I've actually got another question...., If I have a 8/4 and I have the content as 2 rows of col-sm-4 rows in the 8, and I have the 4 as a single column containing 3 divs, how do I get the 4 to slide under the 8 in the form of a row rather than a column...

Comment: you need to open another question since people won't be able to find it within this question (unless it's on the code provided)

Comment: Ok, I'll post another question. MANY THANKS!